# Javascript: Arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments, call, apply

## Function 1

```
function myConcat (separator) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return args.join(separator);
}

var a = myConcat(", ", "red", "orange", "blue");
```

## Function 2

```
function myConcat () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return args.join();
}

var a = myConcat(", ", "red", "orange", "blue");
```

---

Can someone tell me why there is a difference between these two?

Many Thanks

Comment: It is the first param, which you want to differentiate from others. `slice` is removing the first element i.e. separator `, ` from the arguments.

Comment: You can read the separator using `arguments[0]`

Comment: @abidibo, if i don't put anything as a parameter, the result is different.

Comment: yes but you can do this way: https://jsfiddle.net/pp1j3xat/

Comment: @abidibo, But can you tell me why there's a difference between having a parameter there and not having one? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bnmmy852/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has changed, so does the answer.

In 1 the function let's you decide which separator to use, passing it a s the first argument. You don't need to define the separator argument, but can be convenient for readability reasons, that is, a programmer looking at your function can understand immediately that the first argument is the separator used.

The same result can be achieved without defining it though, just assuming the first parameter is the separator to be used:

```js
   function myConcat () {
     // transform array like object in array 
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
     // remove first element and use it as separator
     var separator = args.shift();
     // join other arguments with separator
     return args.join(separator);
   }

   var a = myConcat(", ", "red", "orange", "blue");

   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

here the separator is taken using the `shift` function which removes and returns the first element of an array.

And if you're wondering what the hell is doing the `slice` part, is simply transforming the `arguments` array-like object into a real array

In 2 the separator is fixed, and is the default separator of the js `join` function, which is a comma. Also calling 2 passing a comma as first argument is a NON SENSE, and to write 2 with some sense, you should do something like that:

```
function myConcat () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return args.join();
}
```

and then calling it this way:
`var a = myConcat("red", "orange", "blue");`

Comment: can you take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/bnmmy852/ and tell me why there is a difference?

Comment: your example just works because the `join` js function has a comma separator as default, but in your example you can't decide which separator to use, always comma, while in mine you can still decide the separator passing it as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. But i still don't get why there is a difference between these two
1, https://jsfiddle.net/bnmmy852/2/
2, https://jsfiddle.net/bokqprzp/

why they behave differently? what happened in there?

Comment: the difference is that in 1 you can change the separator, in 2 you can't (and the default join separator is used, which is a comma).
In 1 makes sense to call the function passing a comma as first parameter, in 2 makes no sense at all

Comment: Ahhh! I see! I got it. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the separator to the function, you could also write your code like this:

```
function myConcat () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return args.join(', ');
}

var a = myConcat("red", "orange", "blue");

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Your code will throw exception arguments have no join.

Comment: this is not the same really, since you can't decide which separator to use